# In Birt report, which expression I can use for this ( I am new to SQL)

Tags: report, birt

Table LABORCRAFTRATE have below data,

### Laborcode  Craft

PC90774    Connect
JB62299    Replace
RP61816    Replace

```
If CRAFT = CONNECT,
   then Yes,
else 
   blank in column Connections. 
If CRAFT = REPLACE, 
   then Yes, 
else 
   blank in column Replacement.
```

I need report output like below

### Laborcode Connections Replacement

PC90774   Yes
JB62299               Yes
RP61816               Yes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV640.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT IF(craft='connect','yes','') as connection,
IF(craft='replace','yes','') as replacement
FROM .....
```

this some reference you may read.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp

Comment: getting error, missing right parenthesis.. Tried all options